# How to write a bet settling function in Python

Tags: python, gambling

I'm trying to write a function that takes a sports bet and returns its Net result.

While I managed to accomplish it for bets on total, I couldn't finish settling bets on handicap since it led to some enormous wall of nested if/else statements.

If you are not familiar with betting, an exhaustive test suite should help with understanding what the program is supposed to do.

The main question is how to solve this problem in a way distinct from enumerating all of the possible cases.

Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

```
SUPPORTED_BET_TYPES = ['total', 'handicap']
SIDES = ['home', 'away', 'over', 'under']
BET_OUTCOMES = ['Won', 'Lost', 'Cancelled', 'Half Won', 'Half Lost']


def settle_bet(bet_type, side, points, price, bet_amount, home_score, away_score):
    '''Returns a result of the bet'''

    if bet_type == 'total':
        return settle_total_bet(side, points, price, bet_amount, home_score, away_score)
    elif bet_type == 'handicap':
        return settle_handicap_bet(side, points, price, bet_amount, home_score, away_score)


def settle_total_bet(side, points, price, bet_amount, home_score, away_score):
    '''Returns Net result of the bet on total'''

    outcome = determine_total_bet_outcome(side, points, home_score, away_score)

    if outcome == 'Won':
        return bet_amount * (price - 1)
    elif outcome == 'Half Won':
        return bet_amount * ((price - 1) / 2)
    elif outcome == 'Cancelled':
        return 0
    elif outcome == 'Half Lost':
        return bet_amount * (-1 / 2)
    else:
        return bet_amount * -1


def determine_total_bet_outcome(side, points, home_score, away_score):
    '''Returns the appropriate outcome of the bet from BET_OUTCOMES'''

    total_score = home_score + away_score
    points_score_diff = points - total_score

    if points_score_diff == 0:
        return 'Cancelled'
    elif points_score_diff == 0.25:
        if side == 'over':
            return 'Half Lost'
        else:
            return 'Half Won'
    elif points_score_diff == -0.25:
        if side == 'over':
            return 'Half Won'
        else:
            return 'Half Lost'
    elif points_score_diff >= 0.5:
        if side == 'over':
            return 'Lost'
        else:
            return 'Won'
    elif points_score_diff <= -0.5:
        if side == 'over':
            return 'Won'
        else:
            return 'Lost'


def test():
    # Bets on Total

    # Won or Lost
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.5, 1.90, 100, 3, 2) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 3.5, 1.85, 100, 0, 1) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.5, 1.94, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * (1.94 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 3.5, 1.75, 100, 1, 3) == 100 * -1

    # Won or Lost Or Cancelled
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 2, 2) == 100 * (1.82 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * 0
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * -1

    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 2, 2) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * 0
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 3.0, 1.82, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * (1.82 - 1)

    # Won or Lost or Half Won or Half Lost
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.25, 1.95, 100, 2, 1) == 100 * (1.95 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.25, 1.90, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.25, 1.80, 100, 1, 1) == 100 * (-1 / 2)

    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.25, 1.95, 100, 2, 1) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.25, 1.90, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.25, 1.80, 100, 1, 1) == 100 * ((1.80 - 1) / 2)

    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.75, 1.90, 100, 3, 3) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.75, 1.88, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * ((1.88 - 1) / 2)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'over', 2.75, 1.90, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * -1

    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.75, 1.90, 100, 3, 3) == 100 * -1
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.75, 1.88, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * (-1 / 2)
    assert settle_bet('total', 'under', 2.75, 1.90, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)

    # Bets on Handicap

    # Won or Lost

    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.5, 1.88, 100, 4, 0) == 100 * (1.88 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.5, 1.88, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * -1
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.5, 1.88, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * -1
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -0.5, 1.88, 100, 4, 0) == 100 * -1
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -0.5, 1.88, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * -1
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -0.5, 1.88, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * (1.88 - 1)
    #
    # # Won or Lost Or Cancelled
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 0.0, 1.90, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 0.0, 1.85, 100, 2, 2) == 100 * 0
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 0.0, 1.97, 100, 1, 3) == 100 * -1
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', 0.0, 1.90, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * -1
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', 0.0, 1.85, 100, 2, 2) == 100 * 0
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', 0.0, 1.97, 100, 1, 3) == 100 * (1.97 - 1)
    #
    # # Won or Lost or Half Won or Half Lost
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.25, 1.84, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * (1.84 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.25, 1.84, 100, 2, 2) == 100 * (-1 / 2)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.25, 1.84, 100, 1, 3) == 100 * -1
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 1.25, 1.96, 100, 3, 2) == 100 * (1.96 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 1.25, 1.96, 100, 1, 1) == 100 * (1.96 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 1.25, 1.96, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * ((1.96 - 1) / 2)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 1.25, 1.96, 100, 0, 2) == 100 * -1
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -1.25, 1.86, 100, 0, 2) == 100 * (1.86 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -1.25, 1.86, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * (-1 / 2)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -1.25, 1.86, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * -1
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -1.25, 1.86, 100, 3, 0) == 100 * -1
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', 0.25, 1.97, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * -1
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', 0.25, 1.97, 100, 2, 2) == 100 * ((1.97 - 1) / 2)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', 0.25, 1.97, 100, 1, 4) == 100 * (1.97 - 1)
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.75, 1.90, 100, 4, 0) == 100 * (1.90 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.75, 1.90, 100, 3, 2) == 100 * ((1.90 - 1) / 2)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.75, 1.90, 100, 1, 1) == 100 * -1
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', -0.75, 1.90, 100, 0, 2) == 100 * -1
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 1.75, 1.88, 100, 0, 3) == 100 * (1.88 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 1.75, 1.88, 100, 2, 4) == 100 * (-1 / 2)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 1.75, 1.88, 100, 1, 1) == 100 * (1.88 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'home', 1.75, 1.88, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * (1.88 - 1)
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -2.75, 1.92, 100, 0, 4) == 100 * (1.92 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -2.75, 1.92, 100, 1, 4) == 100 * ((1.92 - 1) / 2)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -2.75, 1.92, 100, 2, 3) == 100 * -1
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -2.75, 1.92, 100, 1, 1) == 100 * -1
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', -2.75, 1.92, 100, 1, 0) == 100 * -1
    #
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', 0.75, 1.91, 100, 1, 2) == 100 * (1.91 - 1)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', 0.75, 1.91, 100, 0, 0) == 100 * ((1.91 - 1) / 2)
    # assert settle_bet('handicap', 'away', 0.75, 1.91, 100, 3, 2) == 100 * -1

    print("All tests passed.")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test()
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better fit for https://codereview.stackexchange.com .

Comment: I have posted it there https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/242728/how-to-write-a-bet-settling-function-in-python However there are a very few views so that it is unlikely to be answered.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel unfortunately, it isn't, see [the guide](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/21002) or [the on-topic section](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). As OP asks for a new feature or a rewrite, the current question is off-topic in its current form and must be rewritten or rephrased before it is on-topic on CR. Please check other sites' on-topic criteria before recommending users to them. Thanks :)

Comment: Pardon; how do you get "new feature or rewrite" from "how to solve this problem in a way distinct from enumerating all of the possible cases"? There are entire classes of standard refactorings that would be missed under the interpretation you seem to be using. Do you still feel this way after seeing the answer I ended up giving OP? Because if *that*'s not what codereview.SE is for, I don't really understand how anyone could ever expect to use it for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few ideas:

1. Instead of returning a string that represents the bet result, return a number that represents the multiplier for the bet result.
2. Instead of separately checking whether the bet was on 'over' or 'under' vs each score difference, use the bet type to normalize the score difference into the amount by which the difference *was in the bettor's favour*.
3. Make use of conditional expressions.

Thus:

```
def settle_total_bet(side, points, price, bet_amount, home_score, away_score):
    '''Returns Net result of the bet on total'''
    outcome = determine_total_bet_outcome(side, points, home_score, away_score)
    bet_size = (price - 1) if outcome > 0 else 1
    return bet_amount * bet_size * outcome


def determine_total_bet_outcome(side, line, home_score, away_score):
    '''Returns the appropriate outcome of the bet from BET_OUTCOMES'''
    amount_over = home_score + away_score - line
    amount_successful = amount_over if side == 'over' else -amount_over

    if amount_successful >= 0.5:
        return 1
    elif amount_successful <= -0.5:
        return -1
    elif amount_successful > 0: # == 0.25
        return 0.5
    elif amount_successful < 0: # == -0.25
        return -0.5
    else:
        return 0
```

As an aside: the lists at the top of your program are not really doing anything right now. But if you want to take a more rigorous approach to this idea - using one of a finite set of values to represent some data - use the standard library `enum` module.

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't work. Have you checked it against my tests? You replaced 'points' parameter with 'line' in the signature in the bottom function, though you forgot to use the new paramater's name in the body. Also there must be a bug in initializing bet_size variable at the top, probably should be -1 instead on 1 in else case. Lists at the top are to help with understading of the problem for non-betting readers.

Comment: I called it `line` as in the over-under line for betting. Fixed the typos/logic, didn't think it through.